# node.js: cannot find module 'request'

Tags: linux, node.js, terminal, npm

I installed [request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request), and getting the error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'request'
```

i've read all the posts about this error, and understand that this is because module requests is not globally found, but i've already tried the 2 suggestions

> npm install request -g

should this install it in /usr/loca/bin ? because i don't see it there.

and

> sudo npm link
>
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/request -> /Users/soulsonic/dev/sandbox/node_test/request

i restarted terminal after each command, but keep getting the cannot find module  error.

**update**

there must have been some sort of conflict in my initial directory, because "npm install request" was not adding "request" under node_modules (there 10 others in there) ..
after switching to a new directory it just worked.

if i run it with -g switch, i do see it bing installed to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/request.

it seems that i just need to update my profile so that above path is automatically added.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Go to directory of your project

```
mkdir TestProject
cd TestProject
```

Make this directory a root of your project (this will create a default `package.json` file)

```
npm init --yes
```

Install required npm module and save it as a project dependency (it will appear in `package.json`)

```
npm install request --save
```

Create a `test.js` file in project directory with code from package example

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body); // Print the google web page.
  }
});
```

Your project directory should look like this

```
TestProject/
- node_modules/
- package.json
- test.js
```

Now just run node inside your project directory

```
node test.js
```

Comment: yeah that's exactly the example i've followed. and i run the npm installer 10 times now.. in my test project and using -g flag. i can see node_modules in my test directory, but request is not in there.. it continues to give me that error..

Comment: because even though I had some weird conflict, these are the right steps to follow. it worked once I did it again in a new directory. I added an update on what happened to me which will probably be rare for others

Answer (score 40):

You should simply install `request` *locally* within your project.

Just `cd` to the folder containing your js file and run

```
npm install request
```

Comment: after "npm install request" i did copy my app.js to the request folder and tried running from there with the same result. and i will need to use it from more than just one project.

Comment: @SonicSoul: You're misunderstanding how node packages work.  `require('request')` looks in `./node_modules/request`, and that's where `npm install` puts it.  You should run `npm install` from the root directory of each app, and you should never touch the `node_modules` folder yourself.

Comment: before running `npm install request`, you should run `npm init`. Follow the prompts which will create a `package.json` in your project folder. Then run `npm install -S request` which will both install the request module into the node_modules folder as well as add request to your package.json file

Comment: @SLaks doest it mean that everytime I install any package I need to enter in its root folder and execute `npm install`? for all of them?

Comment: @Drumnbass: No.  `npm install` installs all dependencies too.

Comment: Mine worked after this workaround. I was previously installing in with '--global'. Thanks.

Comment: @SLaks Exactly what I needed :) Thank you sir!

Answer (score 21):

I had same problem, for me `npm install request --save` **solved the problem.**  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I have met the same problem as I install it globally, then I try to install it locally, and it work.

Answer (score 2):

I tried installing the module locally with version and it worked!!

```
npm install request@^2.*
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if some module you cant find, try with Static URI, for example:

```
var Mustache = require("/media/fabio/Datos/Express/2_required_a_module/node_modules/mustache/mustache.js");
```

This example, run on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 of 64 bits, node -v: v4.2.6, npm: 3.5.2
Refer to: [Blog of Ben Nadel](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem, here is how I got it working..

open terminal:

```
mkdir testExpress
cd testExpress
npm install request
```

or

```
sudo npm install -g request // If you would like to globally install.
```

now don't use

node `app.js` or node `test.js`, you will run into this problem doing so. You can also print the problem that is being cause by using this command.. `"node -p app.js"`

The above command to start nodeJs has been deprecated. Instead use

```
npm start
```

You should see this..

```
testExpress@0.0.0 start /Users/{username}/testExpress
node ./bin/www
```

Open your web browser and check for localhost:3000

You should see Express install (Welcome to Express)

Answer (score 0):

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require.

You have installed "npm", you can run as normal the script to a "localhost" "127.0.0.1".

When you use the http.clientRequest() with "options" in a "npm"  you need to install "RequireJS" inside of the module.

A module is any file or directory in the node_modules directory that can be loaded by the Node. 
Install "RequiereJS" for to make work the http.clientRequest(options).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem while installing the request globally on ubuntu.

```
$ npm install request --global
```

**This solution works when installing request globally:**

Setting the env variable NODE_PATH='/absolute/path/to/node/modules resolved this error.

```
$ export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

However, this will require you to export this variable for each shell session.
A more permanent option is to:

- add this to your `export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules` .bashrc file, then
- run `source ~/.bashrc`to execute the update .bashrc file

Note that the absolute path to globally installed node modules might differ in some cases. For instance, it may be `/usr/lib/node_modules` instead of `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`. Double-check the right path before setting the `NODE_PATH`