# Node.js Error: Cannot find module 'request'

Tags: node.js, npm

Ok so this is a common error and I HAVE read this
[node.js: cannot find module 'request'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482600/node-js-cannot-find-module-request)

The request module IS installed in my node_modules. My complete node app is

```
var r = require("request");


var s = r('http://www.foo.com/');


s.on('data',function(chunk){

    console.log(">>>Data>>> "+chunk);
});


s.on('end', function(){
    console.log(">>>Done!");
})
```

I run my app by simply calling

```
node app
```

But I keep getting the same error

What gives?

My directory structure is

```
app.js
node_modules
    request
        node_modules
            bl
            combined-stream
            form-data
            hawk
            mime-types
            tough-cookie
```

The complete error trace is

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'request'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/foo/Documents/.../app.js:1:71)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

Comment: Is the `node_modules` directory in the script's vicinity? Can you show me your directory structure?

Comment: see my directory structure above. My node version is v0.8.4 and npm 1.1.45

Comment: I also ran npm init to create a package.json file. Is it possible I have a faulty node installation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js: cannot find module 'request'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482600/node-js-cannot-find-module-request)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something looks wrong in your directory structure. I would nuke the node_modules directory and redo the npm command.

It's always a good idea to maintain a package.json file and see the dependencies written out

```
cd getFoo
npm init # answer the qestions
npm install --save request
node app.js
```

Comment: it's all about --save

Answer (score 5):

Go to the root folder of your app

```
cd my-app
```

Delete folder node_modules

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Reinstall package.json

```
npm install
```

Start the server

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and i installed the request package like that: "npm install request --save" and that solved the problem.