# Has npm install just removed all my files?

Tags: node.js, npm, nodes

I was just following these commands:

[Node.js Error: Cannot find module 'request'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269973/node-js-error-cannot-find-module-request)

```
npm init
npm install --save request
node app.js
```

And now when I go to my project directory, all my files are gone. Is there anyway to get them back???

Comment: Did you use following commands? 1. cd getFoo,
2. npm init # answer the qestions,
3. npm install --save request,
4. node app.js

Comment: @HarshalYeole yes

Comment: What were the names of all files removed, after following the above commands?

Comment: Yes the entire directory has been wiped

Comment: .idea, bin, node_modules, public, routes, views... etc etc

Answer (score 1):

TO  clear your thoughts, following commands does not remove files.

```
npm init  // Initialises the npm in your directory and creates package.json file.

npm install --save package_name // Install package in your directory in the node_module folder.
```

So, definitely, you have done something else, which has been causing directory removal or disappearance.

I would suggest you check **trash**.

Can you post history of commands you used? Maybe that would help me understand what happened exactly.

Comment: I followed those commands exactly, nothing is in trash either

Comment: I was moving projects around between my IdeaProjects directory and another directory, but for some reason one has been wiped and its not in trash

Comment: Can you update your question and post history of commands you used?

Also, did my answer help you understand use on npm init and npm install?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Okay, I  knew this commands. and I am sure that this commands, DID NOT REMOVE YOUR CODE....................................................NOW, I want to know how you were moving project to IdeaProjects dir?

Comment: Just moving between two finder windows

Comment: I noticed I made a copy of the project I eventually ended up losing the contents of, and deleted the extra one, but its not in trash. So that's probably what did it