# Http POST with Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I need to use gulp to call a Web API 2 controller method which returns a string. I was given several recommendations on how to accomplish this:

1. node-http
2. [Request Library](https://github.com/request/request) (I was just given the name, but guessing that's it. [SO Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482600/node-js-cannot-find-module-request))
3. I also found [request/request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) which seems to also do what I want.

Is there a "recommended" way to make get/post/etc calls too APIs from gulp? Is one of the above methods better than the others? I can't find much in the way of tutorials or general usage advice.

Comment: Just use any of them. Maybe fetch package is the simplest.

Comment: The recommended way of making HTTP requests from your build tool is not to make HTTP requests from your build tool. That leads to a build you can't reproduce from version controlled history. For a service that uses HTTP, like Swift or S3, you can use their client library.