# Getting "Error: Cannot find module 'request'" even though I have added request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use `request` for my Cloud Function.

I have installed `request` package via `npm install request`. It sits in `node_modules` like every other package:

[image]

However when I try to upload my Cloud Function, I get the following error message:

```
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'request'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/index.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

Here's my `index.js`:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const request = require('request');

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

function getFoursquarePlace(midPoint){
    let url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?" +
    "ll=" + midPoint.latitude + "," + midPoint.longitude + "&client_id=" +
    client_id + "&client_secret=" + client_secret + "&v=" + version + "&radius=" + radius 
    + "&limit=" + limit + "&categoryId=" + categorySet;

    request(url, options, (error, res, body) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error)
    }

    if (!error && res.statusCode === 200) {
        // do something with JSON, using the 'body' variable
            console.log("body: " + res.body);
        }
    });
```

Does anyone know what the problem may be? I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling `request` but still getting the error.

Edit: I've checked `package-lock.json` and the `request` package is in there:

```
"request": {
  "version": "2.88.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.88.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-NAqB3rk3LgxdsfHnTBNwN0E+lHDAJzu7m0328eY08z2/A0hg==",
  "requires": {
    "aws-sign2": "~0.7.0",
    "aws4": "^1.8.0",
    "caseless": "~0.12.0",
    "combined-stream": "~1.0.6",
    "extend": "~3.0.2",
    "forever-agent": "~0.6.1",
    "form-data": "~2.3.2",
    "har-validator": "~5.1.0",
    "http-signature": "~1.2.0",
    "is-typedarray": "~1.0.0",
    "isstream": "~0.1.2",
    "json-stringify-safe": "~5.0.1",
    "mime-types": "~2.1.19",
    "oauth-sign": "~0.9.0",
    "performance-now": "^2.1.0",
    "qs": "~6.5.2",
    "safe-buffer": "^5.1.2",
    "tough-cookie": "~2.4.3",
    "tunnel-agent": "^0.6.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  }
},
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.1.0",
    "geofirestore": "3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: check your package.json file `request` module are available

Comment: It is there, I've added confirmation in my edit @prasanth

Comment: Check `package.json` instead of `package lock .json` . ***Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?*** Did you see this error ?

Comment: Yes you're right, it's not there. Any reason why it wasn't added? Do I manually add it to the file? (i've added the file in my edit)

Comment: do again `npm install request` .check the package.json dependencies

Comment: Manually adding it in `package.json` worked. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js: cannot find module 'request'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482600/node-js-cannot-find-module-request)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen when you "npm install" a dependency to the wrong folder, as I have just realised I did. I have a Vue project in the "src" subdirectory, and an index.js (Firebase cloud function) in the "functions" subdirectory.

Dependencies of the Vue project must be installed with "npm install" in the main directory. In contrast, dependencies of the Firebase cloud function must be installed with "npm install" being run in the "functions" subdirectory. I had accidentally installed the dependency in the main directory, and was breaking my head trying to understand why it was complaining that it couldn't find the dependency (googleapis) until I realised what I had done. The fix was of course to install it in the right place (so it showed up in the right package.json), and uninstall it from the wrong place for neatness.

```
npm uninstall request //removes the module from node_modules, but not package.json or npm uninstall --save request
npm cache clear --force
npm install --save --save-exact request@2.88.0       
firebase deploy --only functions
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue , it turned I was missing to add request@2.88.x
in dependency in package.json file though it was present in devDependencies

[image: package.json]

In case this doesn't resolve try running

**npm audit fix --force**

**firebase deploy --only functions**