# Cannot find module'./config'

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Whenever I type node . in terminal, (I'm using Visual Studio, idk if that matters) it gives me this error:

```
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './config'
```

Comment: why `node .` ? it's equivalent to `node index.js` i think. if you want to launch node intepreter, just use `node`.

Answer (score 0):

For issues related to the terminal, try to install npm locally, it might solve the problem.

(or)

You can make the directory root of your project, as explained in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482600/node-js-cannot-find-module-request)

For issues related to compilation, you need a proper way to reference files relative to application root in Node.JS

Example: `config = require('../config/config');`

The folder named .. is the parent folder helps in making the path to the file, which means we can go up for two levels with this ../

When you compare (.) and (..) , (.) means current location where as .. means two levels up above the current one.

also,

Try checking `./Config` with Caps instead of `./config`